# how handle refresh token service in AWS amplify-js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my react project I am using AWS Cognito user pool for user management, for user authentication, I am using AWS Cognito idToken. after 90min the session will expire, then I need to refresh with new idToken. how to handle the refresh token service in AWS Cognito using amplify-js. I tried with `Auth.currentSession()` I will call this for every 1 hour but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 49):

Calling `Auth.currentSession()` should solve your problem. Amplify-js abstracts the refresh logic away from you.

Under the hood `currentSession()` gets the `CognitoUser` object, and invokes its class method called `getSession()`. It's this method, that does the following:

1. Get `idToken`, `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, and `clockDrift` from your storage.
2. Validate the tokens (i.e. idToken, and accessToken) to see if they have expired or not.
3. If tokens are valid, return current session.
4. If tokens are expired, invoke the `refreshSession()` method of the `CognitoUser` class, which communicates to the AWS Identity Provider to generate a new set of tokens.

All you have to do now is either:

1. Make sure to call `Auth.currentSession()` at regular intervals
2. Always call `Auth.currentSession()` to get your token for each http request that you make.

You could use a wrapper like this:

```
const getAccessJwtToken = async () => {
  // Auth.currentSession() checks if token is expired and refreshes with Cognito if needed automatically
  const session = await Auth.currentSession();
  return session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
};
```

Lastly, this [github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2560) discussion also introduces a very good manual way to refresh your token and introduces a use case for when you should explore that option.

Comment: I think it should be getIdToken() as getAccessToken() didn't work for us.

Comment: @user.io But wouldn't getIdToken() give the idToken? we want the accessToken to be replaced into the api request headers right? Then we use idToken?

Answer (score 7):

Amplify will automatically keep the session fresh so long as it's active (i.e. the user is making api calls, etc.).

If you want to *force* the session to stay active, even though they are not actively using your API, then the easiest thing to do would be to call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` at regular intervals.

Comment: thank you for your replay, for auto-update I need to enable any options in my user pool settings?  and I tried to do this using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` but that also not working for me

Comment: No- Amplify automatically tries to refresh if the access token has timed out (which happens after an hour). Note that you configure the _refresh token expiration_ in the Cognito User Pools console (General settings > App clients > Refresh token expiration (days))- this is the maximum amount of time a user can go without having to re-sign in.

Comment: Amplify have since fixed this and `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` **does not** automatically refresh the session (probably because this is an expensive call). You will need to do something similar to @techie18 solution to force a refresh manually (ie not wait for 1 hour). Basically, you have to get the current session's refresh token, then pass that into `refreshSession`.

Comment: How sure of this are you, considering this point in the documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#managing-security-tokens "When using Authentication with AWS Amplify, you don’t need to refresh Amazon Cognito tokens manually. The tokens are automatically refreshed by the library when necessary." and this conditional in the code: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L895

Comment: Disclaimer: not a amplify expert, but had to use refreshSession.   

We have a custom use case in our app where we need to force token refresh so that the state of the application is aware of changes in the backend. We were relying on calling `currentAuthenticatedUser` which did refresh the tokens up until a few days ago, but this does not happen anymore as accessToken jwt remained unchanged.  it was only when we used refreshSession that it worked again.  Also, it is not clear what’ when necessary' means.

Answer (score 5):

This will hand you back an AccessToken and a idToken.

```
fetch("https://cognito-idp.<cognito-user-pool-region>.amazonaws.com/", {
    headers: {
        "X-Amz-Target": "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ClientId: "<cognito-user-pool-client-id>",
        AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
        AuthParameters: {
            REFRESH_TOKEN: "<cognito-refresh-toke>",
            //SECRET_HASH: "your_secret", // In case you have configured client secret
        }
    }),
}).then((res) => {
    return res.json(); // this will give jwt id and access tokens
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' and refreshed the toke every time it expired and it solved my problem , here is a code snippet for the tricky getJwtToken part :

```
    getJwtToken() {
    if (!this.activeUser) {
      return null;
    }

    const signInUserSession = this.activeUser.getSignInUserSession();
    const idToken = signInUserSession ? signInUserSession.getIdToken() : null;

    if (!idToken || idToken.getExpiration() * 1000 <= Date.now()) {
      if (!signInUserSession.isValid()) {
        const refreshToken = signInUserSession.getRefreshToken();
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          this.activeUser.refreshSession(refreshToken, (err, session) => {
            if (err) {
              resolve(this.logout());
            }
            this.activeUser.setSignInUserSession(session);
            resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
          })
        });
      }
      return Promise.resolve(idToken.getJwtToken());
    }

    return Promise.resolve(idToken.getJwtToken());
  }
```

Comment: Yo have to add all the code, you have this variable "this.activeUser"  is not part of the code, and you don't explain how you can resolve the problem.