# Flutter - AWS S3 Uploaded Data Expire After 1 Day

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I want to Upload Data From Flutter App to AWS Amplify Storage & Show that in Flutter App..
Here is my code :
[image]

And from this Function I get my uploaded file URL:

[image]

but the file working only 1 day after the next day showing this

[image]

Comment: I think your Cognito (Auth) tokens are expiring; nothing to do with S3. Check this post, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375350/how-handle-refresh-token-service-in-aws-amplify-js

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. Put the code directly in your post.

Comment: @Andrija how to perform that in flutter?